# Postgres, count per month

Tags: sql, postgresql

Im using the followig query to get count per day ,

```
select count(*) as counter 
from art.pub 
WHERE createddate > CURRENT_DATE;
```

I want to adjust it and get it  count per current month ,

any tips to adjust my query

Comment: use group by for month

Comment: `psql` is the commandline client for Postgres. `mysql` is a different DBMS. Which one are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PostgreSQL try to use [date_trunc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC)

```
WHERE createddate >= date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this , it will work on MS Sql server

```
select count(*) as counter 
from  ##TBL_TEMP
WHERE DATEPART(MONTH,createddate) > DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE());
```